Is there a way to access an object's static methods without knowing its type beforehand?
I'm trying to implement something like instanceLikesFood() below, but I also want to inherit the child's changes to the static methods.
class BaseClass {
    private static likedFoodsByType = ["tacos"];

    constructor(private readonly individualLikes: string[]);

    public static typeLikesFood(food: string): boolean {
        return !!this.likedFoodsByType.find(food);
    }

    public instanceLikesFood(food: string): boolean {
        // instead of using BaseClass.likedFoodsByType, I want to get the child's overrides
        return !!BaseClass.likedFoodsByType.find(food) || !!this.individualLikes.find(food);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private static override likedFoodsByType = [...super.likedFoodsByType, "burritos"];
}

const childObj = new ChildClass("enchiladas")

In the example above, I believe childObj.instanceLikesFood("burritos") would return false, but I'd want it to return true.

You'd use this.constructor.likedFoodsByType
